# How to run a php file as a cron job in cPanel in Bigrock Shared Hosting service?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I'm trying to run a PHP file that automatically generates a sitemap and pings various search engines via **cURL** as a cron Job.

By hosting plan is a **shared plan** provided by **[Bigrock.in](http://www.bigrock.in)**.

The control panel is **cPanel Pro   1.0 (RC1)**

This is my Current cron command :

```
php /home/myusername/public_html/sitemap_auto.php
```

But this does not seem to work at all. So Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the php binary is  - /usr/bin/php so the cron command to be set up will be

/usr/bin/php  /home/myusername/public_html/sitemap_auto.php

However, it seems more likely that the reason for the cron failing is elsewhere. I'd suggest that you raise a request with our support team and let them know how exactly you are generating the sitemap and which specific commands you are using to ping the search engines.

Answer (score 1):

You can check manual provided by your hosting provider Bigrock

Below are the link for [Cron job](http://manage.bigrock.in/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq1582.html) at big rock hosting

Also you can refer detail [documentation](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/CronJobs) define at in the same page

Please let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: liyakat .. thanks for the quick response ... But you see.. I'm able to set a cron job ... But i just want to know the proper **command** for executing a php file in Big Rock shared hosting (as the location of the php binary varies with hosting providers sometimes)...