# how to display loop elements with in a given time interval?

Tags: php

Is it possible in `PHP` to display any looping with in a interval of time
For Example :-
   I like to display 1 after 5 minute it will display 2.
 Any help will be greatfull. Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this link ...http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_sleep.asp

Comment: You could use `sleep`, but, see how it works. The program will execute it, but, will just show you the result, after time passes. It does, at it says, "Run, sleep till time X, wake and show". Any other way, Javascript/Ajax.

Comment: You should use cron jobs

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Cron Job sample

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
# This file would be say, '/usr/local/bin/run.php'
// code
echo "this was run from CRON"
```

Then, add an entry to the crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /usr/local/bin/run.php &> /dev/null
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18737637/3793639

Answer (score 0):

If you need this in a long time running php script (loop), then you can use time() to get the starttime of each interval.

```
$start = time();
$cnt = 0;
while (1) # your loop
{
  $now = time();
  if($start +(5*60)>=$now)
  {
     $start = $now;
     $cnt++;
     echo $cnt;
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $number) {
    echo $number;
    sleep(60);
}
```

[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: it id returning 0 @litechip

Answer (score -1):

Maybe combine it with flush() that's what you need test it.

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){

        echo "<br> Line to show.";
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";    

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(2);
}

echo "Done.";

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Comment: This is working but when a user open his/her website he has to wait 2second or if haigher may be 24 hour than how he ll do??

Comment: In that case simple sleep wont help you out here[cause you need to have the page to be constantly opened] . You need to use cron for running script in "background" thought you need something simpler. Cron under windows xampp if you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236484/php-cron-job-on-xampp-windows